# Issue to connect to a third party website

Tags: php, asp.net, curl

I have this website [click to see]

[1]: http://www.forumjeep.ca/connect.php and as you can see, its only codes that we see. I'm trying to see the third party website but its not working. I'm able to login with the credentials, but im stuck from there. Here's the code i'm using thanks to Hanshenrik . Any help possible ?

```
<?php
declare(strict_types = 1);
const USERNAME = '???';
const PASSWORD = '???';
header ( "content-type: text/plain;charset=utf8" );
require_once ('hhb_.inc.php');
$hc = new hhb_curl ( '', true );
$html = $hc->exec ( 'https://app.cfe.gob.mx/Aplicaciones/CCFE/Recibos/Consulta/login.aspx' )->getStdOut ();
$domd = @DOMDocument::loadHTML ( $html );
$inputsRaw = getDOMDocumentFormInputs ( $domd, true ) ['aspnetForm'];
$inputs = array ();
foreach ( $inputsRaw as $tmp ) {
    $inputs [$tmp->getAttribute ( "name" )] = $tmp->getAttribute ( "value" );
}
assert ( isset ( $inputs ['__VIEWSTATE'], $inputs ['__EVENTVALIDATION'] ) );
$inputs ['ctl00$PHContenidoPag$UCLogin2$LoginUsuario$UserName'] = USERNAME;
$inputs ['ctl00$PHContenidoPag$UCLogin2$LoginUsuario$Password'] = PASSWORD;
hhb_var_dump ( $inputs );
$html = $hc->setopt_array ( array (
        CURLOPT_URL => 'https://app.cfe.gob.mx/Aplicaciones/CCFE/Recibos/Consulta/login.aspx',
        CURLOPT_POST => true,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => http_build_query ( $inputs ) 
) )->exec ()->getStdOut ();
// hhb_var_dump($html) & die();
$domd = @DOMDocument::loadHTML ( $html );
$xp = new DOMXPath ( $domd );
$loginErrors = $xp->query ( '//*[(contains(@style,"color:Red") or contains(@color,"Red")) and not(contains(@style,"hidden"))]' );
foreach ( $loginErrors as $tmp ) {
    echo "login error!! ";
    var_dump ( $tmp->textContent );
}
if (0 === $loginErrors->length) {
    echo "login success!";
}

function getDOMDocumentFormInputs(\DOMDocument $domd, bool $getOnlyFirstMatches = false): array {
    // :DOMNodeList?
    $forms = $domd->getElementsByTagName ( 'form' );
    $parsedForms = array ();
    $isDescendantOf = function (\DOMNode $decendant, \DOMNode $ele): bool {
        $parent = $decendant;
        while ( NULL !== ($parent = $parent->parentNode) ) {
            if ($parent === $ele) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    };
    // i can't use array_merge on DOMNodeLists :(
    $merged = function () use (&$domd): array {
        $ret = array ();
        foreach ( $domd->getElementsByTagName ( "input" ) as $input ) {
            $ret [] = $input;
        }
        foreach ( $domd->getElementsByTagName ( "textarea" ) as $textarea ) {
            $ret [] = $textarea;
        }
        foreach ( $domd->getElementsByTagName ( "button" ) as $button ) {
            $ret [] = $button;
        }
        return $ret;
    };
    $merged = $merged ();
    foreach ( $forms as $form ) {
        $inputs = function () use (&$domd, &$form, &$isDescendantOf, &$merged): array {
            $ret = array ();
            foreach ( $merged as $input ) {
                // hhb_var_dump ( $input->getAttribute ( "name" ), $input->getAttribute ( "id" ) );
                if ($input->hasAttribute ( "disabled" )) {
                    // ignore disabled elements?
                    continue;
                }
                $name = $input->getAttribute ( "name" );
                if ($name === '') {
                    // echo "inputs with no name are ignored when submitted by mainstream browsers (presumably because of specs)... follow suite?", PHP_EOL;
                    continue;
                }
                if (! $isDescendantOf ( $input, $form ) && $form->getAttribute ( "id" ) !== '' && $input->getAttribute ( "form" ) !== $form->getAttribute ( "id" )) {
                    // echo "this input does not belong to this form.", PHP_EOL;
                    continue;
                }
                if (! array_key_exists ( $name, $ret )) {
                    $ret [$name] = array (
                            $input 
                    );
                } else {
                    $ret [$name] [] = $input;
                }
            }
            return $ret;
        };
        $inputs = $inputs (); // sorry about that, Eclipse gets unstable on IIFE syntax.
        $hasName = true;
        $name = $form->getAttribute ( "id" );
        if ($name === '') {
            $name = $form->getAttribute ( "name" );
            if ($name === '') {
                $hasName = false;
            }
        }
        if (! $hasName) {
            $parsedForms [] = array (
                    $inputs 
            );
        } else {
            if (! array_key_exists ( $name, $parsedForms )) {
                $parsedForms [$name] = array (
                        $inputs 
                );
            } else {
                $parsedForms [$name] [] = $tmp;
            }
        }
    }
    unset ( $form, $tmp, $hasName, $name, $i, $input );
    if ($getOnlyFirstMatches) {
        foreach ( $parsedForms as $key => $val ) {
            $parsedForms [$key] = $val [0];
        }
        unset ( $key, $val );
        foreach ( $parsedForms as $key1 => $val1 ) {
            foreach ( $val1 as $key2 => $val2 ) {
                $parsedForms [$key1] [$key2] = $val2 [0];
            }
        }
    }
    return $parsedForms;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are setting the content type header to text/plain

```
header ( "content-type: text/plain;charset=utf8" );
```

What you need to do is set it to text/html

```
header ( "content-type: text/html; charset=utf8" );
```

I would, however, suggest you re-evaluate how you notify the user of a successful login if you wish to dump HTML after, as this

```
login success!<!DOCTYPE html PUB...
```

is not good at all.

Try and keep everything you want to render inside the  tags, and keep those tags inside your  tags.

Good luck!